# TimeWithZone comparison woes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
>> t = Time.zone.now; a = Account.create(:last_result_at => t); a.reload.last_result_at == t
=> false
>> t
=> Fri, 24 Jul 2009 21:52:16 UTC +00:00
>> a.last_result_at
=> Fri, 24 Jul 2009 21:52:16 UTC +00:00
```

What gives?

Comment: A little more description of what your problem is would be very good.

Answer (score 1):

The usec component was dropped when storing in the db